# c# - chromedriver - ignore-certificate-errors

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use ChromeDriver 2.4.226107 with Selenium 2.45, Google Chrome 42.0.2311.135, Visual Studio 2012, and .NET 4.5. My little test app compiles and runs, but when it launches a new Chrome window, I get this error:

```
"You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certifiate-errors. Stability and security will suffer."
```

I carefully read [this post](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=799) and tried many of the suggested fixes, but nothing worked. A proposed workaround/solution I saw again and again was to do this:

```
options.AddArgument("test-type");
```

This just doesn't do anything with Chrome 42.0. Here is my C# code (console app):

```
using(var driver = new ChromeDriver()) {
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/test.aspx");
}
```

The Chrome window with error inside yellow bar looks like this:

[image]

1. Is there a solution?
2. Is there a better/simpler way to run automated tests in Chrome webapps than Selenium?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know WTH happened, but suddenly this morning this is working perfectly. Last night this same code didn't work. Anyway, in case it helps anyone, here is the FULLY working C# code for chromedriver 2.5, .NET 4.5, and Selenium 2.45 binaries for .NET:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("test-type");

    // Initialize the Chrome Driver
    using(var driver = new ChromeDriver(options)) {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/test.aspx");

        // Get User Name field, Password field and Login Button
        var userNameField = driver.FindElementById("txtUsername");
        var userPasswordField = driver.FindElementById("txtPassword");
        var loginButton = driver.FindElementById("btnLogin");

        // Type user name and password
        userNameField.SendKeys("MyUSN");
        userPasswordField.SendKeys("MyPWD");

        // and click the login button
        loginButton.Click();

        // Take a screenshot and save it into screen.png
        driver.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(@"F:\temp\screen.png", ImageFormat.Png);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Note: To reuse the same Chrome browser window for all your tests, make a static class variable thusly:

```
private static ChromeDriver driver;
```

(In fact you may want to make all your class-level variables static.)

And then do something like the following so that your handle to ChromeDriver can be reused across all your tests:

```
[ClassInitialize] // this only executes ONCE per test-run (not once per test!)
public static void OneTimeSetup(TestContext ctxt) {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("test-type");
    options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
    options.LeaveBrowserRunning = true;
    driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\MyStuff", options);
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
}
```